# Which graphic card is compatible

Tags: graphics-card

I want to upgrade my graphic card on windows PC. I know (per motherboard manual) GeForce RTX 3070 Ti is compatible.

But when I search on google I get a list like:

1. **Gigabyte** GeForce RTX 3070 Ti Gaming OC 8GB Graphics Card
2. **MSI** GeForce RTX 3070 Ti Gaming OC 8GB Graphics Card
3. **ASUS** GeForce RTX 3070 Ti Gaming OC 8GB Graphics Card
   ..

Are all of these still compatible?   My desktop is ASUS.

Here is my setup:

- GeForce RTX 3070 Ti Gaming OC 8GB Graphics Card
- Amd Ryzen 7 3700x 3.6ghz [4.4ghz Turbo] 8c/16t 36MB cache 65W Processor
- Cyberpowerpc Masterliquid Lite 120mm Argb Watercooler
- Crucial Ballistix 8GB DDR4-3000 Memory
- 1TB WD Blue SN500 Series PCIe NVME M.2 SSD
- Windows 10 Home For High End Devices Digital License
- Cyberpowerpc Amethyst 240v Mid W/ Tempered Glass (White) 3 X Argb Fan Retail
- Apevia 800watt Gold 80 Plus Power Supply
- Asus Prime B550M-A M-ATX w/ Wifi, Rgb 1 PCIe X16 2PCIe X1 2 M.2 4 SATA 6GB/S
- XFX AMD Radeon Rx 5700 XT 8GB GDDR6 Navi

Comment: You also need to check that the power supply in the computer can supply enough power to work with the graphics card and the other components in the PC, mainly the processor. What make and model is the PSU you have currently, and the make and model of the CPU?

Comment: You have told us absolutely nothing about your desktop.  So we cannot tell you what graphics card might be compatible.  However, the specifications of each card, are on the respected product page.  Should be a simple task of comparing, your system specifications, to the physical dimensions and power requirements of each product to determine which card will work.

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: Please note that My computer Motherboard Manual does say it support GeForce RTX 3070 Ti.

Comment: So why does this question exist?  Do you think that some genius here knows more about support for your MOBO than the manual for the MOBO?  It is going to boil down to your power supply and *chances are* that it will work.

Comment: The PCI Express interface is fully standardized. You can use add-in cards of any make.

Comment: Thanks! Please put this an answer